# Reduce power consumption for AN7316 amplifier

Tags: power-supply, power, amplifier, integrated-circuit, preamp

I have a pre-amplifier with [AN7316](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjn9erR1djUAhVHVhQKHf1BBnEQFgguMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.rcscomponents.kiev.ua%2Fdatasheets%2Fan7316_idjo3.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHoTHdEnzio-dnLVUIzy0onxt-fFA) from a tape recorder. Currently it draws 24mA from a very small 12V battery (I think it is an A23).

The IC has two parts: a "play" amplifier and a "rec" amplifier. I only use the "play" amplifier (get output from pin 4). Can I shortcut pin 4 and 13 to the ground? Or can I shutdown the "rec" amplifier at all, in order to reduce power consumption? 
[image]

Comment: @solarmike - 
 
You "answered" my question with 3 off-topic questions. Please do provide a CONSTRUCTIVE answer (like Bruce) IF you have one. If you would like to continue the discussion you started, please do it in private chat. Maybe other people will join. Many thanks for your input anyway.

Comment: @solarmike - Thanks for the downwote. Anyway, if you want to see a Constructive answer take a look as BruceAbbott.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't shut the record amp off, but you could try turning ALC off and see if that reduces the supply current. Lowering the supply voltage *will* reduce supply current. At 6V it only draws (typically) 11.4mA.

If you use a buck regulator to lower the supply voltage it can reduce battery current even more. For example if the IC draws 12mA at 6V and the regulator is 90% efficient (at 12mA) then the battery current will only be (6V*12mA)/(12V*0.9) = 6.7mA.

Comment: 1. How do I shutdown the ALC off? 2. Will the amplification factor drop if I drop the voltage from 12V to 6V?

Comment: 1. short pin 7 to GND 2. no (see datasheet graphs with 'Gvc' plot).